# Works in JSFiddle not in web directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

Here is the [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/CPeGK/2/)!

The code works fine except when I insert it in my index.html then the browser cannot resize the icon.

Using the following script tags in my header of the index.html file in my web project

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"/>
```

Do you have any ideas why this is not working?

TY in advance

Here is full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Home page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!--
        David JavaScript code
        -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"/>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#imghover1").mouseover(function() {
                    $("#imghover1").width(295);
                    $("#imghover1").height(54);
                });
                $("#imghover1").mouseleave(function() {
                    $("#imghover1").width(245);
                    $("#imghover1").height(45);
                });
            });

        </script>


    </head>

    <body  id="page1">
        <div class="tail-top">
            <div class="tail-bottom">
                <div class="main">
                    <div id="header">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="first"><a href="index.html" class="current">Home page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index-1.html">Company</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index-2.html">Registration</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index-3.html">IT Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index-4.html">Questionnaire</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index-5.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/button2.gif" class="button1" /></a>
                        <div class="indent2"><img alt="" src="images/icon1.gif" class="alignMiddle" /> &nbsp;<a href="login.jsp">login</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<img alt="" src="images/icon2.gif" class="alignMiddle" /> &nbsp;<a href="#">search</a></div>
                        <div><a href="index.html"><img alt="" src="images/xxcloud.gif" id="imghover1" class="logo" width="245" height="45"  /></a><br /></div>

                        <div class="indent">
                            <img alt="" src="images/slogan.gif" /><br />
                            <img alt="" src="images/title.gif" /><br />
                            <p><strong>Donec accumsan malesuada orci. Donec sit amet eros. consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris fermentum dictum magna. Sed laoreet aliquam leo. Ut tellus dolor, dapibus eget elementum vel cursus eleifend elit. Aenean auctor wisi et urna. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis ac turpis. </strong></p>
                            <a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/button.gif" class="button" /></a><br />
                        </div>
                        <div class="indent1">
                            <a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/banner1.jpg" /></a><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/banner2.jpg" /></a><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/banner3.jpg" /></a><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/banner4.jpg" /></a><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/banner5.jpg" /></a><br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: paste your whole code here so we can help.

Comment: Try adding `http:` before the `//ajax.googleapis...` part.

Comment: whats the best way to show you my code, its too long for comments and I cant answer my question?

Comment: Please send link to page.

Comment: see edit unless you want a full copy

Comment: still not working with an ending script tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"/>
```

should be:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: not working with an ending script tag.  I tried this already anyway

Comment: Works for me, with code you provided, don't forget to add 'http://' ...since it is not complete code - i can just shoot in the dark... maybe you have two same id's... don't know...http://jsbin.com/aharuf/1/edit

Comment: I also specified the protocol and nothing!

Comment: I deleted my website cache, renamed the variabled, deleted netbeans 7.3 cache and nothing!

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question but does the script source of one tag copy over to other <script> tags

Comment: Don't understand your question, but i have feel - this problem is not related to html/jquery. As you can see, html/jquery it self is ok and working. Something related to your directory settings in net beans, probably (i am not user, so i don't know). If Jquery doesn't work, most likely - it is not loaded in page at all... (check console log, or put alerts in script to debug)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this is working for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>



  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#imghover1").mouseover(function () {
                $("#imghover1").width(295);
                $("#imghover1").height(54);
            });
            $("#imghover1").mouseleave(function () {
                $("#imghover1").width(245);
                $("#imghover1").height(45);
            });
        });
    });//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>

<img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/700x1000" id="imghover1" class="logo" width="245" height="45" />

</body>


</html>
```